# jquery mask - query for the time input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to take hour input until 24. I don't know how it could be done, for example I can't give `'H' = [0-2]` and `'h' = [0-9]` because that would allow the user to input upto 29th which I don't want, so is there a way to accept upto 24hrs not 29?

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  //mask code
  $(".timepicker").mask("Hh:Mm:Ss", {
    translation: {
      'H': {
        pattern: /[0-1]/,
        optional: false
      },
      'h': {
        pattern: /[0-9]/,
        optional: false
      },
      'M': {
        pattern: /[0-5]/,
        optional: false
      },
      'm': {
        pattern: /[0-9]/,
        optional: false
      },
      'S': {
        pattern: /[0-5]/,
        optional: false
      },
      's': {
        pattern: /[0-9]/,
        optional: false
      }
    },
    placeholder: "Hh:Mm:Ss"
  });
  //mask code
});
```

Comment: I am not sure but I think you will not be able to validate this when H and h are separated, I think you should 'Hh' : { pattern: '[ here your regexp for 24 hours ]'}

Answer (score 0):

You get acheive this by using only H instead of Hh because h is dependent on H so we can't make the pattern in mask dependent. So if you use only H then writing pattern for H like the below will work

```
/([0-1][0-9]{1}|2[0-3])/
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    //mask code
  $(".timepicker").mask("HH:Mm:Ss", {
   translation: {
  'H': {
     pattern: /([0-1][0-9]{1}|2[0-3])/,
     optional: false
       },
  'M': {
    pattern: /[0-5]/,
    optional: false
  },
  'm': {
    pattern: /[0-9]/,
    optional: false
  },
  'S': {
    pattern: /[0-5]/,
    optional: false
  },
  's': {
    pattern: /[0-9]/,
    optional: false
  }
},
placeholder: "HH:Mm:Ss"
 });
  //mask code
 });
```

This will work !

Comment: now i'm not able to type anything in the input field :(

Comment: Have you changed the pattern to H:Mm:Ss ?

Comment: i have done exactly the same... and now the input text field is not taking any value

Comment: Actually that is a valid 24 hr format regex but I think we need to make it compatible with mask plugin. So two things 1. First remove $ from the 'H' pattern and check 2. Modify H to HH  like this  $(".timepicker").mask("HH:Mm:Ss", {....

Comment: It won't accept 24:59 it accepts only upto 23:59 . Check my sample demo once https://jsbin.com/wasefa/4/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: yea, ' <input type="text" class="timepicker" id="hms" placeholder="00:00:00" style="outline: none;" /> ' <- this refuses to take data in it

Comment: Try this one /([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])/  using HH

Comment: now other fields are working while first one is left blank (i.e. HH)

Comment: Oh ! Cool can you share me your code using jsbin/codepen so that I can look more. Before that use this one /([0-1][0-9]{1}|2[0-3])/ and then try to share

Comment: Nope dude mask won't allow custom regex except its acceptable formats even in the official https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/  demo he is validting time wrong. Better try to use inputmask  https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask to custom javascript. Thanks